# Some Icons of TYPO3 Icon API don't appear

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

In TYPO3 7.6, I used the TYPO3 icon API to display an icon for a new CType.

All worked well on the local machine.

After copying the code to a staging-machine, the icons I used are displayed as "missing" (i.e. the red "default-not-found"-icon is displayed instead.)

If I change my icon to a more common one, like "content-table", it is correctly shown. If I change it to a less popular like "content-briefcase", the default-icon is shown.

Deleting chaches didn't solve the problem.

Do I have to activate/load the icons before use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be depending on the minor version.

I tried it with TYPO3 7.6.15.

There, some of the icon-files where missing in typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/content

After update to TYPO3 7.6.19 everything works as expected